# difficulty with approach to allowing user to input time

Tags: javascript, regex

Stuck on the thinking of this, a user can enter a time into a field in the formats listed below. The time in the end will be saved and formatted to xx:xx 12 hour. I'm allowing flexibility/laziness on the user's part rather than throw strict errors.

**Formats Allowed**

- 1 (1 digit)
- 11 (2 digits)
- 11 1(hours and min)
- 11 10(hours and mins)
- 1110(hours and mins, no space)

**Problems**

I need to somehow take the user's entered time

1. Add prefixed zeros where needed so i get (xx:xx)
2. Add ":" in between hours and mins

Why do I need specifically ":" inserted? I need to save hour and min into separate variables later but I need to reformat the time behind the scenes so that it's ALWAYS xx:xx, having it in a predictable format means I can use JavaScript to split it by the ":" and do what I need to from there.

I'm not looking for the straight answer so much as suggestions because I'm under the assumption i'll need regex.

Comment: how you are panning to get the users input, just as a string?

Comment: @Joseph I'm probably going to have to, the user can submit 10 20pm for example, feels weird if I restrict the person to saying you can only enter 10 20 minus any pm or am. The value is taken from the field and passed onto the function responsible for formatting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/8dabu7d8/7/

```
var number = "11 11";

console.log(format(number));

function format(number) {
    if (number.length == 1  ) {
        return '0' + number + ':00'
    }else if (number.length == 2) {
        return number + ':00'    
    } else if (number.length == 3){
        return number.substring(0, 2) + ':' + number.substring(2) 
    } else if (number.length == 4 || number.length == 5){
        return number.substring(0, 2) + ':' + number.substring(2).trim() 
    }

}
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure your solution before your edit worked

Comment: Sorry one other thing I don't get is why when number.length is equal to 3, why is number getting substringed 2,1?

Comment: Remove 1 you don't need it. Or you can put 3 three instead. I was in a hurry sorry

Answer (score 0):

Using the replace method, you could do something such as :

```
var myRegexp = /(\d{1,2})[ ]?(\d{0,2})/i;
var match = myRegexp.exec(yourString);
var result = match[1];
if(match[1].length == 1)
{
   result = match[1].concat("0");
}
result = result.concat(":");
if(match[2].length != 2)
{
   if(match[2].length == 0){
       result = result.concat("00");
   }
   else{
       result = result.concat(match[1].concat("0"));
   }
}
```

Comment: I'll give it a shot thanks, could you explain the brackets/parentheses in the regex, their purpose?

Comment: Sure!
The `[ ]` part will match a whitespace (`\s` matches linebreaks too). The parentheses are used to have match groups. The `{1,2}` means matching between 1 and 2.

Comment: appreciate that, with your code if the string I pass through for example is 11 11, I get 11: or 9 gets 90:00

Comment: Oh, right for the 9. For the 11, strange - I do get two matches here. Anyway, the timepicker is indeed a better solution (see the other answer)

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to use a time picker which will solve all your overheads and the user experience will also be great.You have a enormous time picker controls available in java script.

here is a simple example

http://jonthornton.github.io/jquery-timepicker/

I feel better to use any of these time picker control.